# Calling Custom Field within Function wrapped with Divs.

Tags: custom-field, functions

Hi all I've created a function that basically allows the user to input the embed code for youtube into a custom field called youtube and this will then be styled on a wordpress post. Now I can get it to work perfectly until I want to wrap some CSS around it. Could you have a look where I'm going wrong. I think it's because I'm closing and opening PHP code? Thanks

```
 <?php
    function youtube(){
        $ytvalue = get_post_custom_values("youtube");
        $youtube = $ytvalue[0]; 
        return '<div class="youtubeVideoWrapper">
                <div class="youtubeVideoHeader"></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>  
                <div class="youtubeVideoOuterContainer">
                <div class="youtubeVideoInnerContainer">';

        return $youtube;

        return '</div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>';

                    }
        add_shortcode('youtube', 'youtube');

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is going to hit the end of that first return and stop. Concatenate the strings and it should start working.

Comment: Update - Ignore the comment below sorted it with google and your help thanks very much :)Hi thanks yeh I just read the code will stop executing after the first return. Any chance you could show me how to concatenate the strings? It's a term im very unfamiliar with.

Comment: Concatenation is as simple as using the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), which is just `.`. So say that I have two strings `$foo = 'string'` and `$bar = 'concatenation'`, `$foo . $bar` would be `stringconcatenation` and `$foo . ' ' . $bar` would be `string concatenation`